# How to prove Halting problem is solvable by oracle machine

Tags: complexity-theory

How can we prove that the Halting problem is solvable by a machine with access to some oracle?

Comment: With what oracle? If you give it an oracle for the Halting problem, it's trivial; if you give it an oracle for some decidable problem, it's impossible. Do you understand how oracle machines work?

Comment: thanks david , I just wanted an oracle for the halting problem and how does it work, I understood this.

Comment: OK, so what don't you understand? Having an oracle for a particular problem means having the ability to solve the problem in a single step. So a machine with an oracle for the halting problem can solve the halting problem by definition. Or are you asking how the oracle itself works? If so, it's not a physical machine: it's a mathematical object that does whatever we define it to do.

Comment: I meant the first one.

Comment: Reza, could you edit your question so it would be clear what you mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An oracle machine is a regular machine, such as a Turing machine, with an attached device that is an oracle.  This oracle, often called a black box to signify that it is not constructible in the real world, answers questions about some set.

For instance if the oracle is a $K$ oracle then it can answer yes or no whether numbers are in the set $K$ (I'm taking $K$ to be the name of the set of natural numbers $e$ such that Turing machine $e$ halts on input $e$).  So obviously the Halting Problem can be solved by a machine that has access to this oracle.